# Complex chain rule

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, differential, chain-rule

Suppose $V_1$ and $V_2$ are open sets in $\mathbb{C}^m$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$, repsectively, $f:V_1\mapsto V_2$ and $g:V_2\mapsto \mathbb{C}^k$ are $\mathbb{R}-$ differentiable. We know that the real chain rule for the differential of $g\circ f$ at a point $z$ gives
$$D_z(g\circ f)=D_{f(z)}g\circ D_zf.$$ Can someone explain how can we prove that
$$\partial_z(g\circ f)=\partial_{f(z)}g\circ \partial _z f+\overline{\partial}_{f(z)}g\circ \overline{\partial}_zf,  $$and
$$\overline{\partial}_z(g\circ f)=\overline{\partial}_{f(z)}g\circ \partial _z f+\partial_{f(z)}g\circ \overline{\partial}_zf?  $$
We use the following notation:
$$\partial _z\varphi=\sum_p\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z_p}dz_p\quad \& \quad \overline{\partial}_z\varphi=\sum_p\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \overline{z}_p}d\overline{z}_p .  $$ Also that would be great if someone knows a reference for that kind of stuff. Thanks.

Comment: What you've written is actually incorrect. I don't like your subscript notation for evaluation at, but — for example — $\bar\partial f(z)$ in the first formula should be $\partial\bar f(z)$.

Comment: I don't know. In my lecture notes this is like that. Do you have a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to avoid your notation and use more standard notation, but you can make the translation. I'm also going to do the case $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ and you can easily generalize it. So we start with
$$df = \partial f + \bar\partial f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}d\bar z.$$
Now, if $z=g(w)$, then
$$dz = \frac{\partial g}{\partial w}dw + \frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}d\bar w,$$
and we get $d\bar z$ by conjugating, so
$$d\bar z = \overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}}d\bar w + \overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}}dw.$$
The chain rule tells us that to compute $d(f\circ g)$ we just substitute these latter expressions. We obtain
\begin{align*}
d(f\circ g) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}dw + \frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}d\bar w\right) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\left(\overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}}dw+ \overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}}d\bar w\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}}\right)dw + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}}\right)d\bar w\,.
\end{align*}
From this you read off that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial w} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}}\,, \quad\text{and} \\
\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial\bar w} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}}\,.
\end{align*}

You will notice this is a lot like the Einstein summation convention in tensor analysis: We sum a product of a $w$ derivative and a $dw$ and a product of a $\bar w$ derivative and a $d\bar w$ in every case. It may be useful to keep in mind that $\overline{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial w}} = \dfrac{\partial\bar g}{\partial\bar w}$ and $\overline{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial \bar w}} = \dfrac{\partial\bar g}{\partial w}$.

Thus, we can finally rewrite this as:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial w} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\frac{\partial\bar g}{\partial w}\,, \quad\text{and} \\
\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial\bar w} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial g}{\partial\bar w}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\frac{\partial\bar g}{\partial\bar w}\,.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think there is something that is obvious in your mind but doesn't click in mine: how would you go from the last two equations to $$\partial (f\circ g)(a)=\partial_{g(a)}f\circ \partial_a g+\overline{\partial}_{g(a)}f\circ \overline{\partial}_ag?$$Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I already told you that equation is wrong. And multiplication becomes composition of linear maps when there are more coordinates (just as the usual chain rule becomes a composition).  As usual with Leibniz notation, $\partial f/\partial z$ is evaluated at $g(a)$ and $\partial g/\partial w$ is evaluated at $a$. Your last term should have $\partial_a \bar g$ instead of $\bar\partial_a g$; I started off days ago saying the equation was wrong. The second equation is likewise incorrect. Sorry I switched $f$ and $g$; I should have checked your post more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for details about the Wirtinger chain rule: the differential of a function of complex variable(s) is the ordinary differential plus some extra terms which turn out to vanish if such a function is holomorphic.
You can find a detailed explanation in the book by Michael Range "Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables": 1st chapter in the proof of Lemma 2.2 (page 20 in my edition).

Comment: Thaks, but I am interested in the formulas for $\partial (g\circ f)$ and $\overline{\partial }(g\circ f)$. Not the formula for $D_z(g\circ f)$. I didn't fine these in your reference, unlese I am mistaken.